# How to reset all the values in c++ during a do-while loop?

Tags: c++

When the user press Y to continue, how do I clear all the previous values for the variables ?

Right now, this code keep stacking all the values when user press Y.
What should I do to clear all the variables' values from previous ?

```
double monthlyPayment; //Get the monthly payment from user
double balance; // formula to calculate the loan.
double interestRate; // get the interest rate from user
double interestPaid;
double total_amount_of_interest_paid;
double initialBala`enter code here`nce; // get the initial cost of the item/loan.
char continueMessage; // to continue the program.
int month = 1;
cout.setf(ios::fixed);  // 2 decimal places for decimal values.
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.precision(2);

do{

cout << "Enter the amount of the loan: "; //Getting the amount of the loan from user.


//Error checking for balance
        if(!(cin >> initialBalance) || initialBalance<= 0.0)
    {
        do
        {
            cin.clear(); //Reset the failed state
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); //Discards up to 1000 characters or until it reaches a new line.
            cout << "Please enter positive numbers only: ";
        }while(!(cin >> initialBalance) || initialBalance <= 0.0);
    }



cout << "Enter the interest rate per month in percentage(%): "; //Getting interest rate from user.


//Error checking for interest rate. If the value is less than 1 means user entered the value in decimal form.
if (!(cin >> interestRate) || interestRate < 1.0)
    {
      do
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            cout << "Please make sure you enter postive numbers and in percentage form: " ;
        }while(!(cin >> interestRate )|| interestRate <=0.0);
    }

cout << "Please enter your monthly payment: ";// Getting monthly payment from user.

//Error checking for monthly payment. Value entered must be positive numbers.
if(!(cin >> monthlyPayment) || monthlyPayment < 0.0)
    {
        do
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
                cout << "Please enter positive numbers only: ";
            }while(!(cin >> monthlyPayment) || monthlyPayment <0.0);
    }



    balance = initialBalance;
    interestRate = interestRate/100;
    balance = balance - (monthlyPayment - (balance * (interestRate)));
    cout << "Your remaining debt on month 1 is: $"<<balance<<endl;

    while(balance > 0)
        {
            if (balance < monthlyPayment){
                balance = balance - balance; // when monthly payment more than balance means the debt is fully settled.
            }else{
                balance = balance - (monthlyPayment - (balance * (interestRate)));
            }
            month++;
            cout << "Your remaining debt on month "<<month<<" is: $" << balance <<endl;

        }
        cout << "Number of months taken to clear the debt: "<<month<<endl;

        total_amount_of_interest_paid = (monthlyPayment*month) - initialBalance;
        cout << "Total amount of interest paid over the life of the loan: "<<total_amount_of_interest_paid;

        //Ask the use whether wants to continue the program or not.
        cout << "\n\nPress 'y' or 'Y' to continue (other characters to quit): ";
        cin >> continueMessage;

}while(continueMessage == 'y' || continueMessage =='Y');










return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please format your code so that people can see better what your problem is. Big, convoluted and sub-optimally formatted code is simply hard to read. Also, I imagine that people down-vote because you present massive amounts of code, at least in comparison to the question. I'm sure your problem is small enough to get into a much smaller example: keep it http://sscce.org ! In addition, what does "all the values" mean? What values? In which context? etc etc. Be precise and clear.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clear the previous values', what do you mean by 'stacking'. I'm not sure what problem you are facing but I suspect that the solution isn't where you think it is. Try describing the actual problem, what do you **see** that is wrong, instead of describing what you think the solution might be.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put a condition statement to check the `continueMessage`, if its `yes` then `continue` else `break` the loop.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to reorganize most of your `do` loop into a function with local variables:

```
do {
    calculateInterest();

   // Ask the user whether wants to continue the program or not.
    cout << "\n\nPress 'y' or 'Y' to continue (other characters to quit): ";
    cin >> continueMessage;

} while (continueMessage == 'y' || continueMessage =='Y');

...

void calculateInterest(void) {
    double monthlyPayment; //Get the monthly payment from user
    double balance; // formula to calculate the loan.
    double interestRate; // get the interest rate from user
    ...
}
```

That way, the variables are implicitly reset each time the function is run.  Doing it this way also helps organize the code more clearly for anyone else who might need to read it.